# how to move UIManagedDocument to iCloud

Tags: core-data, icloud, uimanageddocument, nspersistentstore

What is the code to move UIManagedDocument which has some data from local to iCloud directory?
I understand i need to use migratePersistentStore feature, but when i don't understand how should i do that with a managed document, and there is no examples of how to do this.
Im struggling for 2 weeks now. There are a lot of these questions on stack overflow, but none of them are getting an answer? Is is this hard? Just one method to move existing document to iCloud?

```
-(void)transferFileFromLocalDirectory:(NSURL*)localURL ToiCloudDirectory:(NSURL*)iCloudURL{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
            NSLog(@"Successfully set document ubiquitous");
            UIManagedDocument* doc=[[UIManagedDocument alloc]initWithFileURL:iCloudURL];
            doc.persistentStoreOptions=[self getPersistentOptionsFromDocumentMetadataAtURL:[iCloudURL URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"DocumentMetadata.plist"]];

            [doc saveToURL:doc.fileURL forSaveOperation:UIDocumentSaveForCreating completionHandler:^(BOOL success){
                UIManagedDocument* localDoc=[[UIManagedDocument alloc]initWithFileURL:localURL];
                NSPersistentStoreCoordinator* psc=[[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc]initWithManagedObjectModel:localDoc.managedObjectModel];
                NSPersistentStore* store=[[psc persistentStores]lastObject];
                if(!store){
                    store=[[NSPersistentStore alloc]initWithPersistentStoreCoordinator:psc configurationName:nil URL:[[localURL URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"StoreContent"]URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"persistentStore"] options:nil];
                }
                NSLog(@"store : %@",store);
                NSError* error2=nil;
                [psc migratePersistentStore:store toURL:[[localURL URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"StoreContent"]URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"persistentStore"] options:nil withType:NSSQLiteStoreType error:&error2];
                if(error){
                    NSLog(@"error migrating persistent store:\n%@",error);
                }
            }];
    });
}
```

i get this output

```
2013-12-07 20:15:45.284 iGymPRO[1111:3707] store : <NSPersistentStore: 0x15eb7a20> (URL: file:///var/mobile/Applications/610A9443-002A-42EA-8A66-E4D43F609672/Documents/Data%20Document/StoreContent/persistentStore)
2013-12-07 20:15:45.290 iGymPRO[1111:3707] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Can't find store type for store <NSPersistentStore: 0x15eb7a20> (URL: file:///var/mobile/Applications/610A9443-002A-42EA-8A66-E4D43F609672/Documents/Data%20Document/StoreContent/persistentStore) (class == NSPersistentStore) in {
    Binary = "<8c3b9f3a>";
    InMemory = "<54419f3a>";
    SQLite = "<dc459f3a>";
}.'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this [link explaining UIManagedDocument and iCloud Integration and providing details of the classes and methods involved in doing this](http://ossh.com.au/design-and-technology/software-development/uimanageddocument-icloud-integration/)

Also take a look at [this video showing how the app works when creating UIManagedDocuments and moving them to and from iCloud](http://youtu.be/r9zqxOjAYPo) to confirm its what you are trying to achieve.